# Python 2.7.13 variable accentuation

Tags: python, python-2.7

Ubuntu 17.04 x64
Python 2.7.13

I am having a hard time trying to call a variable with accentuation:

```
└──╼ $python
Python 2.7.13 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:48:08) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170118] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> nomes = ('Mário')
>>> nomes
'M\xc3\xa1rio'
>>>
```

Any tips? :)

Regards
Vitor Jr.

Comment: That's just the internal representation. What happens if you print it?

Comment: Yeah! print was working fine. I was just curious about calling the variable! Thanks! (y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `print nomes` and you'll find that it has what you were looking for.

The `'M\xc3\xa1rio` that you see is just how the special characters are represented by Python.